# Unable to locate an installed package

Tags: package-management, rpm

I just created an RPM and scp'd it to one of my servers at work. I have went forward and done:

`sudo rpm --install supportScripts-0.1-1.noarch.rpm`

Everything installed fine. But when I go to locate it using query:

```
rpm -q supportScripts-0.1-1.noarch.rpm
package supportScripts-0.1-1.noarch.rpm is not installed
```

That's what I get. So I attempted to install it again and I get:

```
[root@slu support]# rpm --install supportScripts-0.1-1.noarch.rpm
        package supportScripts-0.1-1 is already installed
```

Can anyone help me locate where the package installed to and why query is stating it is not installed??

Update: I tried to see if I can erase the rpm:

```
[root@slu support]# rpm --erase supportScripts-0.1-1.noarch.rpm
error: package supportScripts-0.1-1.noarch.rpm is not installed
```

I can't understand why one source is saying it's installed while the other is saying it's not. This is confusing and frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When querying, only supply the name of the package, not the name of the rpm file it came in:

`rpm -q supportScripts-0.1-1` (or just `rpm -q supportScripts`).

EDIT: to obtain a list of the files contained in an installed package:

`rpm -ql supportScripts`

Comment: I used that and got an echo of it's name, is there a way to locate where the package got unpacked to?

Comment: I updated my answer. These things BTW can be found with 15 seconds of googling...

Comment: Thanks. I found that there are no files in my RPM, which doesnt make any sense since there should be scripts in there..

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay more attention when reading man pages - it is:

```
rpm --install PACKAGE_FILE
```

and

```
rpm --query PACKAGE_NAME
```

The packge name doesn't contain the `.rpm` suffix, and usually is understood to be just the name without any versioning/architecture information. When in doubt what the package name is exactly, use for example

```
rpm -qa | grep part_of_name
```

which will list all installed packages and filter out only those matching your search pattern.

Comment: Dude, I am still learning how to do this stuff. Sorry for my ill knowledge but I am learning this stuff as i go.

Comment: I mentioned insufficient attention just as an observation - the small difference just often matters especially with computers, that are supposed to do exactly do what *you tell them* to do... And frankly, the `rpm` man page could be a bit clearer on this very topic. Hint: when something gets frustrating in this particular *"I'm doing it right, why doesn't it work"*, it is often [PEBCAK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEBCAK) (first-hand experience).

Comment: Well I knew I wasn't doing something right but I wanted to know what I was doing wrong, which is why i posted this questions to U&L stack exchange